# How to set or change the desktop background in configuration profile in Big Sur

Tags: big-sur, desktop, configuration-profiles

Is there any way to set the desktop background picture in a configuration profile in Big Sur? This is when using local profile, rather than one set by a server or MDM.

Answer (score 1):

The `com.apple.desktop` payload supports two keys: `locked` if set to `true` will prevent the desktop picture being changed. `override-picture-path` can be used to set the path to the desktop picture. More information is given in the "Desktop Payload" section of the [Configuration Profile Reference](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf).

If you don't want to create a configuration profile by hand you can use a profile editor such as [iMazing's Profile Editor](https://imazing.com/profile-editor).

This payload requires the picture to exist on the device. To my knowledge there is no way of embedding an image within a configuration profile.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. As I didn't need anything else but to change the desktop picture I didn't use extra software, but just modified an example mobileconfig file that I found here: https://github.com/gregneagle/profiles/blob/master/desktop_picture.mobileconfig